# Can I write a private greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

I want to write a greasemonkey script for my client to automate his tasks, however I don't want to share the script with others (as obviously, my client would not be too happy with this!)

How can I do write a greasemonkey script without sharing it with others?

Comment: You just *do it*. Writing a greasemonkey script doesn't necessarily involve publishing it anywhere.

Comment: OK. great! can you tell me then how can I run/install the script in my browser without uploading it to the userscripts site

Comment: Just make a new script. No part of installing the script involves uploading it anywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question is not clear.  But **if you mean, "Can I stop my client from seeing the Greasemonkey script's code and possibly sharing it?"**

Then the answer is **"NO"**.  Anyone using Firefox can see/edit the script's code via the Greasemonkey menu or the *User Scripts* tab in the Add-on manager.

This is by design.  The producers of Greasemonkey (and most script authors) do not want any possibility of hidden or encrypted scripts being foisted on unsuspecting users.

~~~
Additionally, the script source can be seen by anyone with access to the client-machine's file system.

---

---

If you mean:

> How can I run/install the script in my browser without uploading it to the userscripts site?

That's easy...

1. Save your script to to a file, EG *MyScript.user.js*.  Keep track of where you saved it, and make sure it's not in a system `temp` folder.
2. In Firefox, choose *Open File* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>).
3. Navigate to where you'd saved your script and open it.
4. Greasemonkey will pop up a dialog asking if you want to install the script. Press *Install*.

**See ["Installing Scripts" in the documentation](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Greasemonkey_Manual%3aInstalling_Scripts).**

Comment: when I want to share a 'private' script with friends i simply place the .user.js file on my USB drive, plug the drive into their computer and drag and drop onto firefox.
keeping in mind they must have Greasemonkey installed first!

Answer (score 3):

Make site with a link like this

```
<a href="http://yourserver.com/yourscript.user.js">Install special script xx</a>
```

and save your script at

```
http://yourserver.com/yourscript.user.js
```

Grease Monkey and Tamper Monkey will see a javascript file and if it ends with user.js it will ask to install it. Give the url with the install link to your client. You can protect your site with a password.